# How to create concatened primary key?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Hello I'm new to MySQL but I would like to create a unique ID based on two primary keys created in two other tables.

Here is just the part that interests us:

```
CREATE TABLE patient(
id_patient int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...,
PRIMARY KEY (id_patient))

CREATE TABLE surgeon(
id_surgeonint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...,
PRIMARY KEY (id_surgeon))

CREATE TABLE  case(
id_patient int NOT NULL,
id_surgeon int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_case_patient FOREIGN KEY (id_patient) REFERENCES patient(id_patient),
CONSTRAINT FK_case_surgeon FOREIGN KEY (id_surgeon) REFERENCES surgeon(id_surgeon),
CONSTRAINT id_case PRIMARY KEY (id_patient, `_`,id_surgeon));
```

I think i don't get the trick. I wanted the following result :

```
SELECT * FROM case;

id_case  | id_patient | id_surgeon    
32_56    |     32     |     56
18_66    |     18     |     66
```

I know that the speed of calculation will not be optimal but this *id-case* is really necessary and **must** be visible during the select

Comment: why not store as 2 columns and concatenate during select (as a virtual column)?

Comment: Because we need this id for all documents generated from the database. And it is easier to have this ID as the primary key rather than calculating it each time.

But maybe i'm wrong, I dont know... If i'm wrong can you tell me why ?

Comment: You're wrong. Your goal is to have `32_56` visible during select. You can do that using `SELECT CONCAT(id_patient, '_', id_surgeon) as my_id`. If you don't want to perform this "calculation", you can also have a trigger that updates a column using the same `CONCAT` mentioned above. Your primary key should be a regular auto_increment. and seeing that the same patient can probably have the same surgeon at some point later - combination of `(id_patient, id_surgeon)` in `case` table is a bad candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a computed column, and if you really want its values on disk you can persist the computed column

```
CREATE TABLE  case(
id_patient int NOT NULL,
id_surgeon int NOT NULL,
id_case varchar(30) AS CONCAT(id_patient, '_', id_surgeon),
CONSTRAINT FK_case_patient FOREIGN KEY (id_patient) REFERENCES patient(id_patient),
CONSTRAINT FK_case_surgeon FOREIGN KEY (id_surgeon) REFERENCES surgeon(id_surgeon),
CONSTRAINT pk_case PRIMARY KEY (id_patient,id_surgeon));
```

However unless you have the requirement that the pair (patient, surgeon) uniquely identifies a case you should consider adding in an extra field (e.g surgery date)